# Insert arrays elements into database fields MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, insert

I have a database called 'customers' and five arrays called name, address, city, cap, country. In my database i want to create 10 records containing this infos about every customer. With my code all the data is isert into database, but first are inserted all the names, the all the addresses and so on, so i got 50 records instead of 10. How can i fix it?

```
    <?php

$name = array('Alfreds Futterkiste','Ana Trujillo Emparedados','Antonio Moreno Taqueria','Around the Horn','Berglunds snabbkop','Blauer See Delikatessen','Blondel pere et fils ','Bolido Comidas preparadas','Bon app','Bottom-Dollar Marketse');

$address = array('Obere Str. 57','Avda. de la Constitucion 2222','Mataderos 2312','120 Hanover Sq.','Berguvsvagen 8','Forsterstr. 57','24, place Kleber','C/ Araquil, 67','12, rue des Bouchers','23 Tsawassen Blvd');

$city = array('Berlin','Mexico D.F.','Mexico D.F.','London','Lulea','Mannheim','Strasbourg','Madrid','Marseille','Tsawassen');

$cap = array('12209','05021','05023','WA1 1DP','S-958 22','68306','67000','28023','13008','T2F 8M4');

$country = array('Germany','Mexico','Mexico','UK','Sweden','Germany','France','Spain','France','Canada'); 

$conn= mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','preesame') or die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

foreach ($name as $key=>$value)
{
$namess = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value);
$addressess = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$addresses);
$citiess = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$cities);
$capss = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$caps);
$countriess = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$countries);
$insert = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO customers (id,name,address,city,cap,country) VALUES ('',$namess[$key],$addressess[$key],$citiess[$key],$capss[$key],$countriess[$key])");
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are looping on each array, and insert all of them.

Try this:

```
$name = array('Alfreds Futterkiste', 'Ana Trujillo Emparedados', 'Antonio Moreno Taqueria', 'Around the Horn', 'Berglunds snabbkop', 'Blauer See Delikatessen', 'Blondel pere et fils ', 'Bolido Comidas preparadas', 'Bon app', 'Bottom-Dollar Marketse');
$address = array('Obere Str. 57', 'Avda. de la Constitucion 2222', 'Mataderos 2312', '120 Hanover Sq.', 'Berguvsvagen 8', 'Forsterstr. 57', '24, place Kleber', 'C/ Araquil, 67', '12, rue des Bouchers', '23 Tsawassen Blvd');
$city = array('Berlin', 'Mexico D.F.', 'Mexico D.F.', 'London', 'Lulea', 'Mannheim', 'Strasbourg', 'Madrid', 'Marseille', 'Tsawassen');
$cap = array('12209', '05021', '05023', 'WA1 1DP', 'S-958 22', '68306', '67000', '28023', '13008', 'T2F 8M4');
$country = array('Germany', 'Mexico', 'Mexico', 'UK', 'Sweden', 'Germany', 'France', 'Spain', 'France', 'Canada');

$conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'preesame') or die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

$i = 0;
foreach ($name as $names) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name,address,city,cap,country) "
            . "VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $names[$i])."',"
            . "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $address[$i])."',"
            . "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city[$i])."',"
            . "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $cap[$i])."',"
            . "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $country[$i])."')";
    $insert = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $i++;
}
$conn->close();
```

And if i can suggesst you a tip: organize your data like this in a multidimensional array like this:

```
$persons = array(
    array('name' => 'Alfreds Futterkiste', 'address' => 'Obere Str. 57', 'city' => 'Berlin', 'cap' => 12209, 'country' => 'Germany'),
    array('name' => 'Ana Trujillo Emparedados', 'address' => 'Avda. de la Constitucion 2222', 'city' => 'Mexico D.F.', 'cap' => 05021, 'country' => 'Mexico'),
   //more person here...
);
```

Easier to maintaine, and manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

1) Connect to the database **ONCE**. You do NOT have to connect each time in each of your loops

2) Use a **SINGLE** loop, and a **SINGLE** query:

```
foreach ($name as $key => $value) {
   $sql = "INSERT ... (id, name, address, foo, bar, baz) VALUES ('', $value, $addresses[$key], $foo[$key], $bar[$key], etc...)";
   ... run query here
}
```

3) Read up and learn about [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) because you're wide open for getting your server pwn3d.

Comment: again. connect to the database ONCE. you're connecting every single time you run the loop. that's just crazy. and `[key]` is NOT the same as `[$key]`

Comment: Fixed. I still get a lot of 'Undefined variable' and 'Uninitialized string offset: '

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one loop. Write a for loop and use the index/counter to access the values in your arrays. Something like this:

```
for ($i = 0, $i < 10, $i++) {
//insert using index $name[$i], $address[$i] etc.
}
```